# How to inherit CDATA syntax in XML files from HTML syntax in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, xml, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I am trying to create a new sublime-syntax for XML files, which would treat tags inside CDATA as HTML.
I got as far as creating a new sublime-syntax file, copied the original XML rules (opened them via PackageResourceViewer) and found the section I am interested in:

```
contexts:
  main: 
    - match: '<!\[CDATA\['
    captures:
      0: punctuation.definition.string.begin.xml
    push:
      - match: "]]>"
        captures:
          0: punctuation.definition.string.end.xml
        pop: true
```

Here are two lines that I want to add immediately under `push:`

```
      - meta_scope: text.html.basic
      - include: text.html.basic
```

I expected to have all text.html.basic rules inherited, but I observed no change in behavior or color syntax. By behavior I mean I would like to get auto-closing tags to follow HTML rules. That is if my cursor is in the end of `John Q. Public` in the example below and I press tab, I'd like to get a closing `</p>` tag, not `</Body>` (which is what is happening).

```
<Body><![CDATA[
  <div class="to">
    <p>John Q. Public|
  </div>
]]></Body>
```

What I am getting wrong?

Comment: Take a look at `Packages/HTML/HTML.sublime-syntax` for some examples on embedding other languages (CSS, JS).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @MattDMo, the approach worked. Here is what I came up with:

```
- match: <!
  captures:
    0: punctuation.definition.tag.html
  push:
    - meta_scope: meta.tag.sgml.html
    - match: ">"
      pop: true
    - match: '\[CDATA\['
      push:
        - include: 'HTML.sublime-syntax'
        - meta_scope: text.html.basic
        - match: "]](?=>)"
          pop: true
    - match: (\s*)(?!--|>)\S(\s*)
      scope: text.html.basic
```